# telegram use schedule message

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to schedule a telegram bot message to be sent at a specific unixtime.

As from telegrams official api (https://core.telegram.org/api/scheduled-messages) that should be possible by setting the schedule_date flag.

> To schedule a message, simply provide a future unixtime in the schedule_date flag of messages.sendMessage or messages.sendMedia.

However I was not able to set that flag. To be more precisely, I do not even know how to set a flag, or if I am using the correct api.

What I have tried is to use the api directly via the browser (could use curl as well) like so: https://api.telegram.org/botBOT:TOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=ID&text=Test&schedule_date=1653503351

I also did not find any way to access this flag via https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/#description https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#send-a-message, nor https://github.com/nickoala/telepot.

I want to implement this feature in a python environment, but any working suggestion would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**:
I decided to save the intention to send a telegram bot message at a certain unixtime in a database. I then create an infinite loop that checks if there are any unsent messages before the current timestamp. If the loop detects such a message it sends the message and sets a flag, that that message has been sent.

And as promised, here is a fully dockerized example of that behaviour in action: https://github.com/Sokrates1989/nameTheCountDown-lightweight

It creates a bot that you can pass a name and the duration. Once the duration has passed it sends a message with the passed name. Basically a simple countdown that you can give several names, that run simltaniously. As it is a telegram chat, you can modify the way you are informed about the end of a countdown by modifying the notificaiton of that chat.

And here is the Bot in action: http://t.me/NameTheCountdownBot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't do this by bot API itself, and there's no `schedule_date` parameter in `sendMessage` method:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage
And what you've read is for Telegram clients, not bot API consumers.

If you don't really need unixtime, you can simply create a table for scheduled messages with a text, chat_id and a publish_time column (like 22:15), and run a command every minute to look if there's a message for current time to send. Then send the message and delete the record.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feared it might not be that easy. I will clearify my goal and update my question and post a lightweight dockerized project, so that people can start off faster.  I want to create a bot where you can name a timer/ countdown and set the duration. Once the timer/countdown finishes a message shall be sent with the name of that timer. The idea came up when playing a game where there were thousands of timers that you should act upon once they are finished. With the bot, people can easily know what timers finished.

Comment: I decided to use an infinite loop that checks for unsend pending messages. In the edited question is now a fully dockerized example of a lightweight version of the countdown bot. Thanks again, for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `python-telegram-bot` library has a built-in solution for scheduling tasks: The [`JobQueue`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue). This feature is based on the [`APScheduler` library](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/), which you can ofc also use without `python-telegram-bot`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.